# Where to find VS Code Activity Bar's name?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I use `Activitus Bar` move VS Code `Activity Bar` to bottom `Status Bar`. (Activitus Bar's description is [here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Gruntfuggly.activitusbar). )

Now I need add some `Activity Bar` to bottom, But I do not know where to find the real `Activity Bar` name.

The default config is:

```json
"activitusbar.views": [
    {
      "name": "explorer",
      "codicon": "explorer-view-icon"
    },
    {
      "name": "search",
      "codicon": "search-view-icon"
    },
    {
      "name": "scm",
      "codicon": "source-control-view-icon"
    },
    {
      "name": "debug",
      "codicon": "run-view-icon"
    },
    {
      "name": "extensions",
      "codicon": "extensions-view-icon"
    }
  ]
```

As we can see, the `Source Control` name is `scm`, `Explorer` is `explorer`.

Does anyone know where I can find the extensions's (like `GitLens` `TODOs`) config name?